# Problems with deleting messages that were fetched

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Trying to delete messages from a certain user, but nothing happens:

```
bot.js
client.on("message", (message) => {
            if (message.content === '$deleteuser') {

                message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: 10}).then(collected => { //collected is a Collection
                    collected.forEach(msg => {
                        if (message.author.id === '474851505908875266') {
                            message.delete(0);
                        }


                    });
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: try to show message, do you pass condition if "id"?

Comment: @messerbill, the message.delete() is an API call to remove the message from the discord messages history, so I don't see why it should be a problem to iterate through the collection to achieve this

Comment: if this is a copy/paste of your code, I'd say the problem could come from your "if" statement : you are checking the id of your `message` variable instead of `msg`. the same goes for the delete() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your issue arises from your mistaken use of `message` instead of `msg` inside your `forEach()` callback (as [@Gruntzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3393195/gruntzy) has pointed out). As declared, `message` is the message parameter of your event, while `msg` is the message of the `forEach()`'s iteration. Therefore, when you use `message` inside the callback, you're interacting with the original event message.

Secondly, your code would cause a rate limit to occur because of the separate [`Message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) calls. Use [`TextChannel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete).

Improved code:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content === '$deleteuser') {
    try {
      const toDelete = [];

      const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 10 });
      fetched.forEach(msg => {
        if (msg.author.id === '474851505908875266') toDelete.push(msg.id);
      });

      await message.channel.bulkDelete(toDelete);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: doesnt work, error: ```const delete = [];
                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Comment: delete is a keyword in JavaScript, meaning you cannot assign variables to it as it is reserved. Try changing the variable name `delete` to something else

Comment: +1 @Snel23, more problems tho :( `if (msg.author.id === '474851505908875266') .push(msg.id);
                                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
   `

Comment: part 2:  `at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3`

Comment: `.push` has to be called on the array object, ie. the one you renamed